# Query multiple TFS 2015 projects from different collections simultaneously

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is it possible to perform queries in TFS 2015 that span multiple projects? We have two TFS collections with several projects in each, and we need to perform queries for several of at ounce, so for example lets say we have 10 projects in Collection1 and 5 projects in Collection2, we sometimes want to query 2 projects from Collection1 + 1 project from Collection2, in one query. And the same thing with another query with different projects.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible directly from web interface or from Visual Studio interface but you can create your own application that'll use the TFS REST API ([run a stored query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-stored-query)) and it'll query Collection 1 then Collection 2 and at the end it'll merge the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot ds19. Too bad it's not possible out of the box. Maybe I'll just copy projects from collection to the other, so that they are all in one collection, is that worth the hassle?

Comment: @ashilon if you consolidate the projects in one collection then can query out-of-the-box cross team projects